# Using names of loop variables in output file

Tags: list-manipulation, evaluation

Consider a set of lists:

```
lista={{1,2},{3,4},{3,5},{4,8}}
listb={{3,5},{7,6},{2,9},{3,7}}
listc={{1,23},{3,23},{34,56}}
```

I want to do some operation on them and then export the result.

```
Do[
x=Listplot[n];
Export["path"<>ToString[x]<>.jpg,x,"JPEG"]
,{n,{lista,listb,listc}}
]
```

However this doesn't work as x get evaluated in the ToString[] function. I tried using Hold[] on x inside the ToString[] but then it doesn't evaluate the name at all. Im looking for a way to use the evaluated form of x in the plotting and only keep the evaluation up to the name of the variable in the ToString[] function. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are ordered by closeness to the original attempt - I think something like the third approach is the most natural to work with.

#### Approach 1

This approach is the closest to the original in terms of how `n` can be used, but is not very pretty otherwise...

```
Do[
  Export[
    "path" <> (Hold@n /. OwnValues@n /. Hold[x_] :> ToString[Unevaluated@x]) <> ".jpg",
    ListPlot[n],
    "JPEG"
  ],
  {n, Unevaluated /@ Unevaluated@{lista, listb, listc}}
]
```

This relies on preventing evaluation of `lista`,... at two key points:

- In the iterator specification of `Do`: Here, we need to wrap every element of the list in [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html). The second `Unevaluated` is to prevent the list from being evaluated by `Map` (the `Unevaluated/@…` part)
- In the `ToString` part: We need to evaluate one layer of definitions (i.e. we need to insert the value of `n`) using `Hold[n]/.OwnValues[n]`. This gives us something of the form `Hold[lista]`. Then we pass this to `ToString`, where we use `Unevaluated` again. Also, we do this using a replacement rule to have better control over the evaluation.

#### Approach 2

The main idea is similar, but we initially wrap the variables in [`Hold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold.html) to make handling them easier:

```
Do[
  Export[
    "path" <> (n /. Hold[x_] :> ToString[Unevaluated@x]) <> ".jpg",
    ListPlot[ReleaseHold@n],
    "JPEG"
  ],
  {n, Hold /@ Unevaluated@{lista, listb, listc}}
]
```

As mentioned above, the main idea is similar to approach 1. The difference is that `n` is now of the form `Hold[lista]`. This means that we do not have to be so careful when getting the name of the symbol. We just have to use [`ReleaseHold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReleaseHold.html)whenever we actually need to insert the value.

#### Approach 3

There are better ways to label data than to try and extract variable names (while simultaneously preventing their evaluation): [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html)s. Most operations are transparent to the keys, but if you need them (e.g. to build the file name), you can access them using functions like [`KeyValueMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyValueMap.html):

```
lists = <|
  "lista" -> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {4, 8}},
  "listb" -> {{3, 5}, {7, 6}, {2, 9}, {3, 7}},
  "listc" -> {{1, 23}, {3, 23}, {34, 56}}
|>;

KeyValueMap[
  Export["path" <> # <> ".jpg", ListPlot[#2], "JPEG"] &,
  lists
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the break down, approach 1 and 2 is what I was after. I know its not the most elegant or functional way, but I wanted to understand how to hold variables at different points. I used approach 3 in my code before posting this question but I was just curious how it could be done.

Answer (score 1):

This helper function converts precisely the expression given to it to a string:

```
holdToString[s_] := StringTake[ToString[Hold[s]], {6, -2}];
SetAttributes[holdToString, HoldAll];
```

However, this means a little bit of trickery is required to get the iterated variables to appear at all. After all, this doesn't work:

```
Table[holdToString[i], {i, {lista, listb, listc}}]
```

> ```
> {"i", "i", "i"}
> ```

Introducing `With` to perform the substitution works, however:

```
Table[With[{iter = i}, holdToString[iter]], {i, {lista, listb, listc}}]
```

> ```
> {"lista", "listb", "listc"}
> ```

Using this to do what I suspect you're trying to do, an initial approach would be something like this:

```
Do[
  With[{iter = n},
    x = ListPlot[iter];
    Export["path"<>holdToString[iter]<>".jpg",x,"JPEG"];
    ];,
  {n, {lista,listb,listc}}
];
```

However, this is fundamentally flawed because replacement with the defined list happens in the iterator variables. To preserve variable names reliably, it'd probably be best to switch to a more function-oriented paradigm, such as:

```
export[x_] := 
  Export["path" <> holdToString[x] <> ".jpg", ListPlot[x], 
   "JPEG"];
SetAttributes[export, {HoldAll, Listable}];

export[{lista,listb,listc}];
```

Comment: I'm not sure this approach will work, as the values `lista`,... have values assigned to them

Comment: @LukasLang Very true, see update. I think this should work efficiently for your scenario.

Comment: Works as intended.